# Haskell (.) for function with multiple operands

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, composition

The `(.)` operator has the signature:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f $ g x
```

This looks a bit similar to the [*composition function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition) in primitive recursive functions with one *g*.

I'm not interested in extending the number of *g*-functions, but (a number of) functions that apply the `(.)` function on a function `g` with multiple operands. In other words something like:

```
(..) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(..) f g x y = f $ g x y
```

A search on [*Hoogle*](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28c-%3Ed%29-%3E%28a-%3Eb-%3Ec%29-%3Ea-%3Eb-%3Ed) doesn't result in any function. Is there a package that can handle this with an arbitrary number of operands?

Comment: You're looking for the [composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html) library.

Comment: @bheklilr: yes, that's it. Why doesn't this show up in *Hoogle*?

Comment: Hoogle doesn't search all of hackage, but you can use [+composition](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28c+-%3E+d%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+d+%2Bcomposition) to search a particular package, but that doesn't help you find the package to search.  You can use [fpcomplete's](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=%28c+-%3E+d%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+d&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09) version of hoogle which searches more packages by default.

Comment: Jasper Van der Jeugt has a generic operator doing precisely this. See [this blog post](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-10-17-generalizing-function-composition.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer-ify my comments:

Multi-argument function composition operators are very easy to define, and luckily someone has done this for you already.  The [composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html) package has a nice set of operators for you to use to compose functions in this manner.  I also find that instead of using haskell.org's hoogle engine, [fpcomplete's](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=%28c+-%3E+d%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+d&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09) version searches through more packages making it easier to find what I'm looking for.