# Why isn't composing two functions working?

Tags: haskell, types

Apart from readability and loss of generality, what is wrong with the following definition:

```
maxPlusOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
maxPlusOne = (1+) . max
```

The compiler will complain that it can't deduce `Num (a -> a)` from `+`.
But it seems to me what it needs is `Num a => a -> a`, which is precisely the type of `(1+)`.

Here's the error:

```
<interactive>:5:52:
    Could not deduce (Num (a -> a)) arising from a use of ‘+’
    from the context (Ord a, Num a)
```

Comment: `Num a => a -> a` is not the type of `(1+)`.

Comment: @ErikAllik: yes it is. If I type `:t (1+)` into ghci, it tells me `(1+) :: Num a => a -> a` - exactly that.

Comment: (but that is, of course, not the same as `Num a => Num (a -> a)`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's inspect the individual types:

```
max :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
```

Okay, this takes an `a`, and returns a function that takes an `a` and returns an `a`.

```
(1 +) :: (Num a) => a -> a
```

This is simple enough. It takes a number `a` and adds one to it.

If we recall that `a . b` is equivalent to `\q -> a (b q)` we get this from your definition:

```
(1 +) . max   ==   \q -> 1 + (max q)
```

Can you see the problem? You're passing a type `a -> a` to `(1 +)`, **because `max` is only getting one argument.**

---

This is how to fix it, whilst keeping pointfree style.

```
maxPlusOne = (.) (1 +) . max
```

This expands to

```
maxPlusOne = \q -> (1 +) . max q
```

which expands to

```
maxPlusOne = \q1 -> \q2 -> 1 + (max q1 q2)
```

Which is your desired function.

---

You could also define another type of composition:

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> d)
(.:) f g a b = f (g a b)
```

and then define

```
maxPlusOne = (+ 1) .: max
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you interpret the `.` too mathematically (as in `f` "after" `g`). The `.` is simply:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So its semantical meaning is that it takes one parameter `a`, then calls `g` on `a`, and then call `f` on `g`. You can define it as:

```
(.) f g x = f $ g x
```

Although Haskell extensions are proposed (like [this one](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-10-17-generalizing-function-composition.html)) that use the type system to derive how much "parameters" to transport, and some have written this in template Haskell, it is not a standard feature.

**How can you solve it?**

Simply query at least one parameter `x` in the head of your function:

```
maxPlusOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
maxPlusOne x = (1+) . max x
```

or specify it fully:

```
maxPlusOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
maxPlusOne x y = (1+) $ max x y
```

or use extensions on `(.)`.

If you use [jaspervdj's extension](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-10-17-generalizing-function-composition.html)

```
maxPlusOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a
maxPlusOne = (1+) $.$ max
```

Comment: It is not wrong to understand `(.)` as `f` after `g`. It's just that, in `f . g`, `f` and `g` take just one argument -- and indeed *all* Haskell functions take just one argument.

Comment: @duplode I think that's what many beginners have trouble with: the idea that all Haskell functions take one argument, and that seems to be the case here.

Comment: To which "extensions on `(.)`" do you refer?

Comment: @duplode: but in mathematics, in general that is regardless of the number of arguments to `g`. As AJFarmar says, because of the currying aspect of Haskell, `. max` ouputs a function Int -> Int

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28532836/67579) on the subject. The implementation can be found [here](http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-10-17-generalizing-function-composition.html).

Comment: "but in mathematics, in general that is regardless of the number of arguments to g." That doesn't make sense. Mathematical functions have a single domain and codomain. They always "take one argument". Composition is defined for `f . g` when `g : X -> Y` and `f : Y -> Z`, just like in Haskell.

Comment: @CommuSoft That isn't a "Haskell extension". It's just normal Haskell code.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: indeed, and *f(x,y)* as far as I have always interpreted it is a tuple as input. Anyway given the question it seems the OP was confused about the `.`. Furthermore I don't see why to make a distinction between libraries and extensions. People have already enough on their minds. But no problem if you want to do so.

Comment: `f(x,y)` is, but `f(x)(y)` is not. I don't make the distinction. Libraries and extensions are two different, well defined things. I merely point out the distinction.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: yes, that's the currying principle. And your point is... Furthermore why do we have this waste-of-energy discussion anyway. As said before, it looks like the OP (and a lot of people had a slightly different view on the `(.)` operator).

Comment: My point is that you are making incorrect statements that might further confuse the OP.

Comment: That's why stack overflow made sure one can add multiple answers to a question, and nature made sure there are enough people with no lives to give answers (and comments) on SO ;). Most people (probably including the OP) seem to have problems with the fact that in Haskell (although it looks syntactically that way), have no functions with more than one parameter while some mathematical books seem to suggest these (and work with these).

Comment: "I don't see why to make a distinction between libraries and extensions. People have already enough on their minds." -- Because if you don't people will be even more confused when they meet [actual extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html).

Comment: @duplode: from the moment a language supports (Turing complete) metaprogramming, you can turn almost all extensions into libraries and vice versa.

Comment: @CommuSoft But we aren't talking abstractly about an arbitrary language; we are talking about Haskell, in which those terms mean different things.

Comment: @duplode: and there comes in the part that Haskell has its own [template programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell) which facilitates thus meta programming...

Comment: @CommuSoft ... which has no bearing on the fact that "library" and "extension" mean different things when talking about Haskell.

Comment: @duplode: No, an extension means that the compiler will accept "more" than the grammar originally defined by the programming language so to speak. With template programming, you can instruct your compiler to do this. Furthermore it is the same as the data/programming tradeoff. Because of Rice's theorem a lot of concepts in computer science are rather "unstrictly defined". Furthermore as said before this is a non-discussion (it's already a comment about a comment). Please invest your energy in something more useful than this discussion ;).

Comment: @CommuSoft "Please invest your energy in something more useful than this discussion" -- Funny how I was about to say exactly the same. If you think that lecturing me on a topic that is wholly unrelated to the issue at hand somehow frees you from conceding the point, I guess you should consider ways of making the discussions you engage in more useful.